# C++ Compiler problems with rasterbar libtorrent API

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to compile to no avail.

Here's the code that's causing problems:

```
using namespace libtorrent;

const address addy;

new ip_filter();

ip_filter.add_rule(addy, addy, ip_filter::blocked);

s.set_ip_filter(&ip_filter);
```

The error that I keep getting is:

```
mytorrent.cpp:1338: error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token
mytorrent.cpp:1340: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
```

Here is void set_ip_filter():

```
void set_ip_filter(ip_filter const& f);
ip_filter const& get_ip_filter() const;
```

Finally, here is the ip_filter class:

```
template <class Addr>
struct ip_range
{
        Addr first;
        Addr last;
        int flags;
};

class ip_filter
{
public:
        enum access_flags { blocked = 1 };

        ip_filter();
        void add_rule(address first, address last, int flags);
        int access(address const& addr) const;

        typedef boost::tuple<std::vector<ip_range<address_v4> >
                , std::vector<ip_range<address_v6> > > filter_tuple_t;

        filter_tuple_t export_filter() const;
};
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: `c` tag removed: `using`, `namespace`, `new`, `::`, `&` (reference??), `public:` among possibly other constructs are invalid in C

Answer (score 0):

You're using `new ip_filter()`, which would create a new instance of the `ip_filter` class on the heap. But you're not assigning the result of `new` anywhere. Then you are attempting to access the methods of `ip_filter` as if it was an object and then pass it around as if it was an object. `ip_filter` is a class, not an object, it simply tells the compiler how to make an object of type `ip_filter`. To actually use it you need to first create an instance of the `ip_filter` class. Then you can access it's methods and members from that instance.

```
ip_filter *my_filter = new ip_filter;
```

You do not need parentheses as you are not passing any arguments, it also tends to confuse the compiler as it looks like you are declaring a function called 'ip_filter', returning type 'new', taking no arguments. Then you can access the `ip_filter` methods via the instance pointed to by `my_filter`

```
my_filter->add_rule(addy, addy, ip_filter::blocked);
```

then do as before, but without the `&`, as it's already a pointer.

```
s.set_ip_filter(ip_filter);
```